# find accumulated frame difference energy image

Tags: matlab, difference

I have gait recognition system using matlab. I want to find accumulated frame difference energy image (AFDEI) from frame difference image.By weighted average method, the AFDEI is obtained, which can reflect the time characteristic. Next formula shows how to calculate the accumulated frame difference image:

```
(,) = 1/N Σ  (,, )     where Σ from t=1 to N
```

This is my frame difference images (5 image )

[frame difference images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3jmH8.png)

I want to find accumulated frame difference energy image (AFDEI) like this :

[result image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6HFyG.png)

I am try to sum 5 image and taking average put it give my a very different image .

So how to find AFDEI ?

Answer (score 0):

I gave a shot at this:

There is some sort of post processing filtering after averaging the images.

This is the result from averaging:

[image]

And this is after applying a mode filter with a 3x3 window to the previous image:

[image]

So I'd say that your target image is using some sort of *smarter* colouring algorithm. Not sure at this, but it's like it overlaps the borders of the original frames, then fills the resulting zones with the mode/modal value of the AFDEI

---

EDIT: Mode filter used above

```
function target = modeFilter(origin)
  %origin is a monochrome IMG matrix
  %being lazy with the margin, you may resize to filter the borders,
  %without OOB exceptions.
  target=origin;
  [h,w]=size(origin);
    for x=[2:w-1]
    for y=[2:h-1]
    target(y,x)=mode(origin(y-1:y+1,x-1:x+1)(:));
  end
  end
end
```

Comment: thank you for your replay. Can you help me in how coding this?

Comment: I don't have time to try coding a better filter, but I've posted the mode filter I used.

Comment: thank you for your help . I will try and see how make it better

Comment: I am beginner in matlab . what is plain averaging? . I am search put I don't get any information about it.

Comment: I meant plain in the sense of simple, without applying weight coefficients, see `mean()`

Comment: do you mean that you use mean() then modefilter? it given my different result . not like your result above

Comment: Yes, the only issue might be the colorspace. You need grayscale 0:255 , not mono 0:1

Comment: please can you put code of using mean?  thank you for all your help